# ThreeJs OrbitControls is not working in ReactJs

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

```
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
extend({ OrbitControls });
```

```
const Orbit = () => {
  const { camera, gl } = useThree();
  return <OrbitControls args={[camera, gl.domElement]} />;
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
      <Canvas style={{ background: "black" }} camera={{ position: [3, 3, 3] }}>
        <Orbit />
      
        <axesHelper args={[5]} />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This  is the error I'm getting in the console
Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor OrbitControls cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score 1):

`OrbitControls` from `three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls` is not for React Components.

[@react-three/drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei) can help you.

[Example](https://drei.pmnd.rs/?path=/story/controls-orbitcontrols--orbit-controls-story)

or

```
const { camera, gl } = useThree();
useEffect(
  () => {
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, gl.domElement);
      return () => {
        controls.dispose();
      };
  },
  [camera, gl]
);
```